# Isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{D}$ such that lines become circular arcs

Tags: plane-curves

I'm currently working on a hobbyist math project that require taking lines on an infinite plane, and projecting them onto a finite (euclidean) surface such that intersections are preserved.

Does there exist an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{D}$ (the complex unit disc) such that lines become circular arcs?

Comment: Do you know [Möbius tranformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)?

Comment: @quid Not until now.  Based on the wikipedia summary, I think this directly answers my question.  You can feel free to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad it is usefl for you. I will post an answer later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common class of maps that takes lines to circular arcs are [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). They are most commonly considered on complex numbers, but this translates to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

A Möbius transformation of the (extended) complex plane is a map $z \mapsto \frac{a z + b}{c z +d}$ with $ad - bc \neq 0$.